# Haskell xor not work for mapping

Tags: function, haskell, xor

I have a problem of using `xor` function in `Data.Bits` module
like a code below

```
import Data.Bits

andFunc :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
andFunc xs ys = zipWith (\x y -> x .&. y) xs ys

xorFunc :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
xorFunc xs ys = zipWith (\x y -> x xor y) xs ys
```

When I try to apply `andFunc` with arguments of `[1..10]` and `[2..11]` (arguments are just arbitrary array)

it works. (Does not write here, but `orFunc (.|.)` also works)

but some reasons, `xorFunc` does not.... and says

```
<interactive>:74:1: error:
    ? Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Enum ((a -> a -> a) -> t -> c)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    ? When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a t c.
              (Enum ((a -> a -> a) -> t -> c), Enum t,
               Num ((a -> a -> a) -> t -> c), Num t, Bits a) =>
              [c]
```

Do you know why?

Running Environment:
   GHC 8.2.1 with no flags
   Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Thank you guys for answering my stupid question :$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use functions in infix notation you have to use backtick syntax.

```
xorFunc :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
xorFunc xs ys = zipWith (\x y -> x `xor` y) xs ys
```

but this can be solved a bit simpler by not writing this as a lambda expression

```
xorFunc :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
xorFunc xs ys = zipWith xor xs ys
```

and applying eta reduce (twice), i.e. omitting parameters that are occurring in the last position and can be fully derived by the type checker.

```
xorFunc :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
xorFunc = zipWith xor
```

Answer (score 3):

Infix functions are spelled with punctuation and can be made prefix with parentheses; e.g. `x + y` can also be spelled `(+) x y`. Going the other direction, prefix functions are spelled with letters and can be made infix with backticks; e.g. `zip xs ys` can also be spelled `` xs `zip` ys ``.

Applying that to your case, this means you should write one of `xor x y` or `` x `xor` y `` instead of `x xor y`.

Answer (score 3):

`xor` is a regular function name, not an operator. You need to enclose it in backquotes to use as an infix operator.

```
xorFunc xs ys = zipWith (\x y -> x `xor` y) xs ys
```

That said, your lambda expressions aren't necessary; just use `xor` as argument to `zip`:

```
xorFunc xs ys = zipWith xor xs ys
```

or simply

```
xorFunc = zipWith xor
```

(Likewise, `andFunc = zipWith (.&.)`; enclose the operator in parentheses to use it as a function value.)